# How to remove notification when application is killed by the system?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-notifications

I am developing an Android application that notifies a user when data is uploaded to the internet from one of my activities. When the user closes the application through the menu I have implemented, I execute code to remove the notifications I have placed:

```
notificationManager.cancelAll();
```

The problem is the user can kill my application through the multitasking menu (the more likely way to quit) and the code is not executed.

I thought over riding the onDestroy method would solve my problem:

```
    @Override
public void onDestroy()
{
    super.onDestroy();
    notificationManager.cancelAll();
}
```

however, this method does not seem to be called every time the application is quit from the multi-tasking menu.

Is there a way to remove my notifications before the system kills my process?

Thank You!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, I think better way to handle this doesn't exist. System **should** invoke method *onDestroy()*, but you have no guarantee it does.

[onDestroy Android Reference](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onDestroy%28%29)

> There are situations where the system will simply kill the activity's hosting process without calling this method (or any others) in it.